# Twilio SMS body containing hyper link (with parameters) appears broken

Tags: php, twilio-php

I am trying to send a SMS where in the body contains hyper link with parameters. For example:

```
You can now track your order here: http://shoppingwebsite.com?order_id=987654321&product_id=55
```

When I send this using the php sdk provided by twilio I get a SMS with a broken link (I have tried urlencode and addslashes but no luck). Any idea I get the links to appear and work properly in the received SMS?

Here is the complete code:

```
$sms = "You can now track your order here: ";
$sms .= "http://shoppingwebsite.com?order_id=987654321&product_id=55";
$client = new Client(TWILIO_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
$client->messages->create('+19876543210', array(
            'from' => TWILIO_SENDER,
            'body' => $sms)
        );
```

Comment: can you add the code that you are using to send the message

Comment: PS dont post your keys

Comment: You should shorten your url.

Answer (score 0):

Going through all the SMS I had previously received from various service providers I realized that none of them had a url with parameters. Like this:

```
http://shoppingwebsite.com?order_id=987654321&product_id=55
```

They usually use a tiny url, something like this:

```
 http://shopng.wbsite/98765432155
```

So it looks like I will have to minify my url and avoid all the '?' and '&' symbols in the url.